# C# Winforms Chart Re-Draw is SLOW

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

So I'm trying to develop a C# Winforms app that grabs a burst of data (like 300 or so time, value samples) from a data acquisition device and charts it. Kind of like an oscilloscope. So I press a button control and it grabs the data, processes it, and plots.

And no matter what I do, the re-draw of the Winforms chart takes over 1 second. I've done some Stopwatch investigation, and it seems like the culprit is just the slow refresh of the chart, not the data processing. And the data grabbing takes only maybe 10mSec or so.

I'm using data binding to bind some List<>'s to the chart, and the following code is what gets run each time I try to update.

Does anyone know if this is just the standard response of a Winforms chart, or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

```
private void PlotDataBurst(int numSamples)
{
    xVals.Clear();
    yVals.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++)
    {
        xVals.Add(processor.processedDoubleArray[i, 0]);
        yVals.Add(processor.processedDoubleArray[i, 1]);
    }

    chart1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
        delegate
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xVals, yVals);
        }
        ));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout`

Comment: I just tried bracketing my DataBindXY statement with SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout and it made zero difference. Why do you think it would help?

Comment: Just copypasted your code into an empty solution with  default winforms chart on a form. With 300 items in both lists the chart invoke completed in 4ms on first run and sub 1 ms in all subsequent executions. Thats 1k+ difference with what you are observing. There must be something else going on, something not visible in the code in your question.

Comment: Thanks much. Appreciate the help. You've got me thinking that maybe while the data grabbing of a burst of 300 samples from the device is fast, maybe there's something that's causing a long time between subsequent grabs of 300 samples from the device, and it has nothing to do with the chart response.

Comment: Are you sure you are not blocking the main-thread anywhere? Or you have some handled exceptions? `.Invoke` will block the current thread, and while you can use `.BeginInvoke` to avoid this, you need to ensure it is threadsafe to do so.

Comment: I tracked down the culprit and it was my data acquisition device (an Arduino). When it receives a request in string format, it has a default delay of 1 second timeout. Which means even if it receives a complete string, it waits 1 second unless you explicitly tell it that the string is complete. So I had to tell it to look for a "\n" end of line string and it will stop waiting.